# Convexity of "perturbed" convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, convex-geometry

Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and that we have the following "perturbed" quadratic form:

$$Q(x) = x^\intercal A x + x^\intercal B + x^\intercal F(x)$$

where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $(A+A^\intercal)$ is positive-definite, $B\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and the nonlinear mapping $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded, i.e. $\Vert F(x) \Vert \leq \gamma$.

I'm interested in the following question:

*Old question: Is there any $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $Q(x)$ retains convexity under the presence of $F(x)$?*

***New edited question: Can I find a condition on $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ such that I can guarantee convexity of $Q(x)$ under the presence of $F(x)$?***

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, simply let $F(x) = -2Ax$ when $||2Ax||\leq \gamma$ (and 0 otherwise) and you will always have a negative definite quadratic locally somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a million for your comment. I think I've failed in asking the question. I've made the corresponding edits!

Comment: I think the trick with the function I proposed is that it will fail no matter how small $\gamma$ is, since it always is negative definite when $||2Ax||\leq \gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

This fails already in dimension 1. For any $A,B,\epsilon$, you can find $C\gg 1$ such that

$$ f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + x \epsilon \sin(Cx)$$

is not convex.

Comment: Thanks a million for your comment. I think I've failed in asking the question. I've made the corresponding edits!

Comment: @NicoF. Yes, you can find a condition on $\gamma \in \mathbb R$. The condition is $\gamma \le 0$. Also if you use $\epsilon \sin x^2$ instead of $\sin (Cx)$ then its never convex, which is worse (the nonlinearity now doesn't depend on $A,B,\epsilon$)

Comment: Thanks! Though $\gamma$ cannot be negative, no? It's a bound on $\Vert F(x)\Vert$, which is always positive.

Comment: @NicoF. $|F|\le 0$ implies $F=0$.